# How to map array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have my array of object "messages" 
i want to calculate the number of items that have "seen:1"

```
const messages = [ 

 { id: 66, seen:1, tourist_full_name: "Khouloud Ben Abddallah" },
 { id: 102, seen: 0, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez" },
{ id: 103, seen: 0, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez" },
 { id: 104, seen: 1, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez" },
{ id: 105, seen: 1, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez" }
];
```

for example here i want to create a variable that can be like this

```
var SeenCount=3 ;
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: use js filter to solve this: messages.filter(function(msg) {
 return msg.seen === 1;
})

Answer (score 1):

Use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to increment based on the seen property of each object. Our default value is 0 and it will increment in each iteration of our loop depending on the `seen` property value

```js
const messages = [ 

 { id: 66, seen:1, tourist_full_name: "Khouloud Ben Abddallah" },
 { id: 102, seen: 0, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez" },
{ id: 103, seen: 0, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez" },
 { id: 104, seen: 1, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez" },
{ id: 105, seen: 1, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez" }
];


let a = messages.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return acc + item.seen;
}, 0);

console.log(a);
```